# Saving data from AS3 to database.. what is the best method?

Tags: database, flash, actionscript-3, amf, amfphp

I'm developing a two player turnbased game with flash, and i need to save data to database.

At the moment i am using AMFPHP. Works great.

Problem is i'm starting to have quite much information - different kind little things like x, y, hp, path, activeskills... etc. Every time i add something i have to code it to AS and PHP and modify DB structure.

So is there better solution to do this?

I would love to send AMF packet from flash to PHP and save it to DB. Other player could just load this AMF packet from DB ..but i guess that is not possible. Couldnt find any working solution from web.

**Ideal DB structure for me would be:

*id,gameId,gameData*

So how should i "compress" all data to 'gameData'?** Array, amf, string..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You could save a binary file to the SQL DB. For example, MySQL has a field type of [BLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) to hold your data Object. I just can't remember if the data Objects get serialized automatically when transmitted via AMFPHP or will you have to do some serialization.
- You could encode the data Object via [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and save it to the SQL DB.
- The most elegant way I can think for solving this problem is to write the gameData as a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json) formatted string.

Comment: Thank you! Binary was the keyword for solution i was trying to understand. It took a while 'cos amfphp 2 seems to have bug with ByteArray, so i had to go down to 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

AMF isn't the issue: the truth is that you haven't yet completed your app and you're seeking to use a shortcut that negates much of the benefit that AMF provides (e.g. strong typing).

You need to finalise the parameters you need to exchange / save, normalise the storage of that data and update your AMF classes accordingly.

Comment: That is the absolute truth. But then again, i really dont see the point to write couple hundred lines of code - just for transfer the data. Now when i am able to send VO - i guess that is the correct term :) - i can focus to complete my app without worries. I like to have adaptive core - if that makes any sence :)